# Decrypt a string in PHP, crypted in JS with crypto

Tags: php, cryptography

I'm trying to decrypt a string in PHP, I can do it in JS, but I can't do it via PHP.

New in cryptography, I try to recover my original string, but it can't find a solution.

So I have this code below in JS :

```
const p1 = ['abc', 1, 'def', 'hij'].join('a');

let p2 = crypto.createHash('md5').update(p1, 'ascii').digest('hex') + 'a' + p1 + 'a';
while (p2.length % 16 > 0) p2 += ' ';

let result = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-ecb', 'aeda94ad8azd', '').update(p2, 'ascii', 'hex');
```

this code in PHP :

```
$p1 = implode('a', ['abc', 1, 'def', 'hij']);

$p2 = hash('md5', $p1, false) . 'a' . $p1 . 'a';
dd($p2);

while (strlen($p2) % 16 > 0) $p2 .= ' ';

$result = openssl_encrypt($p2, 'aes-128-ecb', 'aeda94ad8azd', 0);
```

JS Result :

let p2 result = 7fbe3256bd8e9ac3e9b2e2ac9c1c812aaabca1adefahija
p2 result after while = same as P2 with one space at the end
let result = a7222dbd06b1ae0ea421ac968eba780f0e0e23317c25bab0ecf423b6ff95f1e25ede0432af1a8b17c56e682193c55516

PHP Result :

$p2 result = 7fbe3256bd8e9ac3e9b2e2ac9c1c812aaabca1adefahija
$p2 result after while = same as p2 with one space at the end

$result = wE5FpEuPuWdL8D06y/jiqRB7kehRcLcBmI16AncqsKWeeqWm8Tj08anFBrnD0JWCP5/ihLo0AUZr0/+MBDjQvw==

---

I do something wrong in openssl_decrypt ? I don't use the right function ?

Waiting for your help thank you all.
Have a nice day

Comment: The NodeJS reference code generates an _Invalid key length_ error, which is not surprising since a 12 bytes key is invalid for AES. AES-128 requires a 16 bytes key. I.e. the posted ciphertext must have been generated with a different key. The PHP code, on the other hand, silently expands the key to 16 bytes by padding with 0x00 values, which is why it works. Please post _complete and consistent_ test data, otherwise no repro is possible!

Comment: Thanks a lot for response, effectively the key was not valid, I put random data not to reveal the real key and data.
I didn't pay attention to this detail when making the post, sorry.

But the main thing is that the problem was finally solved by transforming the content of the result variable with bin2hex() and OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING as option
Thanks to @KIKO Software

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a try, but you're using Javascript in Node.js which I don't use. Still, it could be useful to give an answer because I got somewhat closer to the result you want.

First of all I noticed that your JS result is in hexadecimal whereas the PHP result is probably in Base64. Some conversion is required. I had to use the raw result, and remove the padding to get a hexadecimal string that's as long as yours. The PHP code is:

```
$raw    = openssl_encrypt($p2, 
                          'aes-128-ecb', 
                          'aeda94ad8azd', 
                          OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING);
$result = bin2hex($raw);
```

Now the result is:

```
c04e45a44b8fb9674bf03d3acbf8e2a9107b91e85170b701988d7a02772ab0a59e7aa5a6f138f4f1a9c506b9c3d09582
```

Same type (hexadecimal) and length of string, but not the same. There are two things that could cause the difference:

- The character encoding of the file. I can't check the node.js one.
- The keys might be treated differently. In node.js it has to be in UTF-8 and I think it is binary in PHP.

Anyway, I hope this is somewhat useful.

Comment: An exact match of the ciphertexts is not to be expected, because the posted key is invalid for AES-128. Note that your code and the OP's differ in the padding of the plaintext, you use 0x0a (LF) (this is the only way to generate the ciphertext you posted), the OP applies 0x20 (space).

Comment: @Topaco: Ah, yes, that padding was one of my many experiments which I forgot to change back. I changed it back to a space now, but the result still doesn't match that of the OP. Perhaps that is indeed because of the validity of the key, as you say.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I finally missed the bin2hex that I totally did not think of...
I had tried both options, finally OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING did the job !
And sorry, indeed I changed the dataset and the key without paying attention to the length

Comment: @ThéoDulieu: Are you saying that, with the correct key, it now works?

Comment: Yep, just adding OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING as option parameters and convert result of openss_decrypt with bin2hex

Comment: @ThéoDulieu Nice.